# Is it mandatory to use an ALIAS when we are doing some operation on the column?

Tags: exception, db2, alias

Folks,
Is it mandatory to use an ALIAS when we are doing some operation on the column?

Ex: **select upper(col1) from table1**
when i am trying to retrieve the resultset by rs.getString("col1"), it was giving this exception 
**COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.DB2Exception: [IBM][JDBC Driver] CLI0611E  Invalid column name. SQLSTATE=S0022**

when I changed the query to:
**select upper(col1) as col1 from table1** and used rs.getString("col1"), it is working fine.

So, **is it mandatory to use an ALIAS when some function like upper,trim,lower was applied on a column???**

I am using: DB2 8.2, Type 2 driver

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression UPPER(COL1) is **not** the same thing as COL1.

Compare this:

```
$ db2 "describe select col1 from session.t1"

SQLDA Information

 sqldaid : SQLDA     sqldabc: 1136  sqln: 20  sqld: 1

 Column Information

 sqltype               sqllen  sqlname.data                    sqlname.length
 --------------------  ------  ------------------------------  --------------
 453   CHARACTER           10  COL1                                         4
```

To this:

```
$ db2 "describe select upper(col1) from session.t1"

SQLDA Information

 sqldaid : SQLDA     sqldabc: 1136  sqln: 20  sqld: 1

 Column Information

 sqltype               sqllen  sqlname.data                    sqlname.length
 --------------------  ------  ------------------------------  --------------
 453   CHARACTER           10  1                                            1
```

Notice that the column names in each result set (sqlname.data) are not the same.

So, you would have either have to use a column alias or use rs.getString("1").

Answer (score 0):

Try `rs.getString("upper(col1)")` instead? Typically column names in the result include any functions that were applied for that column. Otherwise, you couldn't have results for things like `SELECT MIN(col1),MAX(col1) ...`